# What's the process for making a PS4 game?

Tags: playstation4

Now that Sony has said that devs can self publish for PS4, I'm betting that a lot more people will be interested in producing games for that platform.

What is the process for getting the SDK, documentation, and testing environment for a PS4?

Comment: You should contact Sony and ask them.  But most likely this information simply isn't available yet since the PS4 isn't yet released.

Comment: Yep, probably a bit early for this. I imagine that the games that were announced with its release were specially contacted by Sony a while back about making a game for the PS4.

Comment: An early estimation would be that it would be at least twice as difficult as signing up as an iOS / Windows Appstore developer. Granted, those are made to be easy, but also have signup fees. You'd also likely need a PS4 itself, and no one has them yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thus far, there is no indication that Sony's self-publishing option for the PlayStation 4 is actually an *open* publishing environment (like the PC). You still need to become a registered developer and that still involves being vetted and approved by Sony, licensing hardware, et cetera.

According to this [press release](http://us.playstation.com/corporate/about/press-release/scea-partners-with-worlds-most-talented-developers-to-expand-industry-for-all-ps-platforms.html):

> For more information about the SCEA Publisher and Developer Relations
>   Group, please visit: http://us.playstation.com/develop or email
>   selfpublish@playstation.sony.com.

You will note that the linked site details a four-step process to register, but notes that, before applying, the following requirements should be met:

- Form a corporate entity and have a tax ID number.
- Have a static IP for your company that Sony can whitelist for developer network access.
- Be physically located in US, Mexico, Central America, South America, or Canada.

The actual online application form asks for various other things an established company should have, as well as information about your development history and published titles, six-month product development plan, et cetera.

Comment: This seems to be centered around SCEA. Is there any corresponding information from SCEE/SCEJ, or is this all there is?

Comment: The links on that page for SCEE and SCEJ Dev/Pub support ([for example](https://www.companyregistration.playstation.com/SCEInternetApplications/AreaNewLicensee/MainSystem/CFModules/NewLicensee/snl_master_template.cfm)) go to a similar registration process for developers. I'm not able to dig up a similar press release on the EU site, though; either they haven't published one or I'm bad at searching.

Comment: Please note that the corporate entity formation is not indicated as required but "strongly recommended". Though I don't know the implications of not forming one.

Comment: [This version of the PlayStation  Partner Registration](https://partners.playstation.com/apex/PO_AccountAppliPTR?lang=en) has fields for other countries & indicates additional questions for EU devs can be sent to SIEE via PS_Partners_Registration@scee.net