# Can I release any sort of app or game on the PlayStation Store?

Tags: playstation4

I'd like to develop a game, and try it out mainly on the Playstation 4.

Can I build *any* game, or app, and release it on the Playstation Store? Or does Sony only allow what it wants in the store, much like Apple and the AppStore? Note that I'm not asking *how* to build a game, but whether or not there are restrictions that would prevent me from releasing certain kinds of games or applications to the Store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the process for making a PS4 game?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57312/whats-the-process-for-making-a-ps4-game)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I don't think this is a duplicate. I'm not asking how to develop a PS4 game. I'm asking "Does Sony allow me to develop *anything* for the PS4". I've added some notes to the question to clarify it's intent. Thanks!

Comment: As long as it is legally developed on an approved DevKit or supportes engine, and it is of sufficient quality on par with other games in the platform you should have no issue having it published in the store. Just don't do anything too gory/immoral/problematic.

Comment: You know, there's a reason that there's virtually no games from indie developers on the PS4, it's costy to license something

Comment: @Bálint - thanks for the feedback, but trying to sell it on the store is different  than seeing if my game will run on the PS4. I'd like to develop it cross platform, and just test it out mostly on the PS4, since it's the console I own and like, and my kids like. My first platform would probably be PC, but that doesn't hook up to my TV as easily for fun testing with my kids/friends!

Comment: No, I meant having a developer account for PS4 is a lot of money ($500 at least)

Comment: @Bálint - ahh... didn't realize that - good point for sure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't release "anything" on the Store. So yes, to *some* extent the store, like all software portals like it (including Apple's App Store, Steam, Xbox Live) could be considered a "walled garden."

The question is *how* walled, really. Unfortunately details on the licensing agreements you sign when you become a licensed PlayStation developer aren't public (at least, not that I could find), so it's difficult to provide solid examples sans legal entanglements.

That said, the Store requires a license agreement to publish to, and it would be baffling and foolish for Sony not to include a clause in that agreement that would allow them to block the publishing or distribution of your product if they deemed it inappropriate for their store. After all, they have their brand image to worry about and consumers won't really care if you are selling a horribly inappropriate or scammy game on the store, they'll focus on the fact that Sony *let you*.

Anecdotally, by browsing the store you can see very few things labelled "apps" (as opposed to "games"), so it's unlikely that Sony will want you to try to sell, for example, a spreadsheet program.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I guess "how walled" is the question... but it does sound like it's more relaxed than the AppStore, from what others have suggested, so that's nice to know. And like you point out, they're all mostly walled to some extent, but it seems Android's Market is easier to get into then say the AppStore, so it got me wondering... thanks again!