# Are there special APIs used to make PS4 games?

Tags: playstation4

Game engines can build games for PS4, but how are those engines written to support it? Is there any special kind of support, API or something provided by the PS4? Does it have like a new programming language or new specification like OpenGL or DirectX?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Consoles are just a different kind of computer, like a phone for example, so writing software for them isn't a fundamentally different problem than writing software for other hardware / OS combinations. They have specifications for interfacing with the system features, but the details are generally available only to registered developers and protected by NDAs. What is it about them that you're trying to find out?

Comment: I've edited the question. Please check now.

Comment: If you're interested in becoming a PS4 developer, [the place to get information and apply is on the Sony site](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/develop/). The afore-mentioned NDAs will limit how much detail we can offer you on a public channel like this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["What's the process for making a PS4 game?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57312/whats-the-process-for-making-a-ps4-game).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. All major consoles have proprietary APIs (which may include graphics APIs). Most of these APIs are non-public.

Engines that support those consoles will have abstraction layers that write against those APIs where required.